# Why IntelliJ IDEA gives advice for Exception?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, exception, nullpointerexception

```
public static List<String> arithmeticProblemToList(**String arithmeticProblem**, boolean resultIsRight,
                                                   double rightResult,
                                                   List<String> previousArithmeticProblemsList) throws Exception {

    Check.checkNotNull(arithmeticProblem);
    Check.checkNotNull(resultIsRight);

    if (resultIsRight)
        previousArithmeticProblemsList.add(arithmeticProblem + "\t\tRICHTIG");
    else {
        previousArithmeticProblemsList.add(arithmeticProblem + "\t\tFALSCH " + rightResult + " wäre richtig");
    }

    return previousArithmeticProblemsList;
}

public static <T> void checkNotNull(T object) throws IllegalArgumentException {

    if (object == null) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Der Parameter darf nicht null sein.");
    }
}
```

Why does IntelliJ give me an advice that the if the String `arithmeticProblem` is null I will get an Exception and for example if `resultIsRight` there is no advice.

Comment: `boolean`s cannot be null; `String`s can be.

Comment: OK thanks for the advice

Comment: "Advance" : it does not mean what you think it means.

Comment: Ohh I am sorry it should be "advice "

Comment: Note that the generics in your `checkNotNull` method are unnecessary: just drop the `<T>` and use `Object` instead.

Comment: And when I want to use this method to check whether a list is null?

Comment: A `List` is an `Object`. Try it.

Answer (score 2):

In Java, there are two different types of data types: Primitives and References.

A boolean is a primitive and cannot be null in any way. It's either true or false, but never null.

A string however is a reference type, and references can be null.

Read more about primitives here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: Is it useful to check whether a parameter is null?

Comment: Not if it can't be null.

Comment: Not that way. You have to often check if something is null in an if statement like this: `if (myVar != null)`
Also, if my answer has helped you please give me an upvote and accept it :)

Comment: @Aenadon note that the correct term is "reference type", rather than object: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.1